# SignalR and Tabs , windows , cloned frames?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I created a simple app which accept a text message from a client and reply **to that specific connection** : "Hey I got your message" , and besides that , broadcast the message to all others.

Piece of code :

```
 1     protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
 2       {
 3                return Connection.Send(connectionId, "Welcome!");
 4       }
 5        
 6     protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
 7       {
 8         Connection.Send(connectionId, "Connection " + connectionId + " I got your message " + data);
 9         return Connection.Broadcast(data);
 10      }
```

All is OK.

<kbd>Question #1</kbd>
Does `Connection ID` is 100% unique to the initializer ? what about if I clone a browser tab ?, or cloned Iframe ? from my testing it is unique. but I need to make sure.

<kbd>Question #2</kbd>

looking at line #8 , I couldn't write `return Connection.Send` because the other line won't be executed . however I think , that way , I will lose the TASK<> return value . what if i'll need it ?

`OnReceived` returns a `Task` but currently it returns just the `Connection.Broadcast(data);`'s task and  (as I was saying - I'm losing line's #8 task return object.)Im afraid im doing something wrong here. or maybe I'm not ?

Who uses this task result in the app cycle anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Yes connection ID is always unique
2  The Connection.Send will not return a value that is returned via the client, SignalR does not support that.  However, if you're interested in just waiting for it and getting the status of the task you can do .Wait() on the Connection.Send() or you can ContinueWith,

Aka

```
Connection.Send(...).Wait(); // If there's an error this will throw
return Connection.Broadcast(data);
```

OR

```
  Connection.Send(....).ContinueWith(task => {
        if(!task.IsFaulted) 
        {
            // Task ran successfully    
        }
        else 
        {
            // Something went wrong when sending, you can get the exception from the task
        }
    });
    return Connection.Broadcast(data);
```

Comment: tnX , Q: in your second example , the return might be running prior to the task execution...?

Comment: Correct, if you wanted to ensure order you could wait on the task.

Comment: Can you please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626566/first-arbitrary-messages-in-signalr-has-no-messageid) ?