# SignalR signals every 10 seconds?

Tags: signalr

I wrote a simple [**app**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604848/signalr-and-tabs-windows-cloned-frames) with SignalR and then I left the computer.

When I came back , after couple of hours , i've noticed this :

[image]

It seems that my app got signaled every 10 seconds.

- why is that ?  ( I didn't write it) , where can I configure that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does this so that load balancers and proxies and other network devices that love to kill idle connections don't end up killing your connection. A classic example is the azure load balancer which kills idle connections after a minute.

The other reason SignalR sends keep alive pings is so that the client can detect network disconnects. The client side is set to expect a keep alive on a specific interval and when 3 of them are missed it'll drop the connection and try reconnecting.

Answer (score 2):

GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive has a default value of 10 seconds