# First arbitrary messages in signalR has no messageID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I wrote this simple code which  --when connected , should yield

- "FIRST !"
- "Welcome"
- 3 messages ( timer)

This is the code :

```
int i = 0;
protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
{
  
    //first message
    Connection.Send(connectionId, "FIRST !"); //first message

    //last messages
    Timer _timer = new Timer(RunMe, new    {con = connectionId, req = request}, 2000, 1000);    

    //second message
    return Connection.Send(connectionId, "Welcome!"); //second message


}

void RunMe(dynamic state)
{
    if (i < 3)
    {
        Connection.Send((string) state.con, "Loop " + i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

and here the JS code ( inside `document.ready` block) :

...

```
connection.received(function (data)
        {

        $('#messages').append('<li><b>data received = </b>' + data +
                                  "<b>ConnectionId =</b> " + connection.id + 
                                  '<b>MessageId = </b>' + connection.messageId + '</li>');
    });
```

**I do get all responses.**

But if I press f5(refresh)  -- these are the typical responses :

[image]

Refresh again ,

[image]

It seems that the first message **never** gets a `messageID` :

And later messages **sometimes** get messageID and **sometimes** not.

## ps

I thought to myself , maybe it's an initialization speed problems , so I tried this :

[image]

And again , the response was :

[image]

- What's going on here ? why the first messages doesn't get messageID ?  how can I fix that ?

Comment: what is your SignalR version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SignalR 1.1, connection.messageId is set [after](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.JS/jquery.signalR.transports.common.js#L260) all of the connection.received handlers have been called for a batch of messages.

Message IDs are really only meant to be used by SignalR internally, but in SignalR 2.0 connection.messageId will be set before the connection.received handlers are called.

Comment: Not yet. Prereleases will be available in the coming months. Again, this won't change SignalR functionally, and Message IDs are really only meant to be used by SignalR internally.

Comment: @qub1n [Yes](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.0.3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.JS/jquery.signalR.transports.common.js#L355). connection.messageId is set before connection.received handlers are called in SignalR 2.*. What do you plan on using the messageId for?

Comment: I used it for chat. I have downloaded some signalR 0.5 demo. I just wanted to know if I should have rewritten it to signalR 2.0. Finally it works for me too now :-) Thank you.

Comment: Just know that if you are checking `connection.messageId` when you receive a message, it can appear as if several messages in a row have the same messageId. This is the result of the way SignalR batches messages. The SignalR client only needs the messageId for the last message in each batch, so that's all the server sends. That's one of the reasons I say in my answer that Message IDs are meant for SignalR's internal use.